# Should I use every Dicom slice of a Dicom series?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, image-processing

I have a skull fracture CT scan dataset, consisting of fracture or normal cases. My question is: Let's say patient-1 has a skull fracture, and his CT scan has 300 Dicom slices. Now should I label every Dicom slice of his CT scan as fractured when I feed these 300 slices into a CNN?

Comment: Why do you label each slice? Isn't CT scan just a 3D image of the skull?

Comment: True. I did not question properly. I meant what if when I convert every Dicom slice to jpg.

Comment: But, why do you treat every slice of the same person as a separate training sample? Wouldn't it make more sense to use 3d conv-nets?

Comment: You are correct. So it is wrong to label every JPG(assuming I converted Dicom to JPG) of a single person's CT scan slices?

Comment: Why convert to JPG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you don't want to label every slice.**

It sounds like you're doing **classification**, as opposed to **segmentation**. For a segmentation problem, you need to classify every *pixel*, which can be laborious work. I'll assume you're doing classification.

#### Get started with 2D images

While you're learning, it might be to treat this as a 2D problem. Choose the most representative slice for each patient and train a 'regular' 2D convolutional neural network to classify the images. This would be a good learning experience, and will let you try a lot of different neural networks.

Note that if you choose to use multiple images per patient, you must be careful not to mix them across training and validation datasets. This would constitute 'leakage' of information from training to validation (e.g. see this [famous example](https://twitter.com/andrewyng/status/931026446717296640)).

Once you have got to grips with the data, the problem, etc...

#### Then move to 3D

This is really a 3D problem, and the state of the art would be to apply a 3D convolutional neural network. [Here's a recent survey of such methods](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.00218.pdf); there are plenty.

The labels are still just whatever classes you have ('fractured', 'not fractured', etc), and you will have one label per 3D training image. Each training image will be a 3D array/tensor — so all your training images will stack into a 4D hypercube.

*Disclaimer: I don't deal with 3D medical images, but I do deal with 3D geophysical images.*

Comment: Excellent answer. I have already trained on 2d CNNs but suspected I made a mistake when I labeled every CT scan slices. So I was thinking to move to 3d CNN. However, my Dicom slice depth is not always the same for all patients, one patient might have 300 slices, another patient may have 25 sliced. How will I deal with this depth problem?

Comment: I mean, I don't want to downsample a Dicom series, because my dataset is quite small. But in the case of oversampling, I fear synthetic data won't add much value as many Dicom series has only 25-30 slices. So what are my remaining options?

Comment: That's a tricky question, and probably worth posting in a new Q. Unfortunately I think you need to reconcile the sample intervals — otherwise the convolutional kernels don't really mean anything. Maybe compromise by regularizing to 50 slices?